# Code coverage with Visual studio 2012 With Nunit Adapter

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

I am using Nunit and VS2012 Code coverage runner for code Coverage . Code coverage Window displays all the TestDLL but not the implementation dll .

For Eg If i have MyCompany.presentation.Unit and MyCompany.presentation . Codecoveage window displays MyCompany.Presentation.Unit and coverage information .How can i make it to cover the implementation also .